# What is the Workflow metadata type?

Tags: salesforcedx, workflow, metadata, xml

I've got a couple of `XML` metadata files in a `workflows` folder, the contents of the files are really basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workflow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

What are these?

Both of them have names which correlate to a custom object.

Where in setup would I find them? as I have nothing in:

```
Setup > Process Automation > Workflow Rules
```

My instinct is to delete them, but I don't know what I might break by doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a necessary file, as it has no content, so it would be safe to delete. This file would contain Workflow Rules, Workflow Tasks, Workflow Alerts, Workflow Field Updates, and Workflow Outbound Messages for a given object (either standard or custom). If it had content and you deleted it, this could remove the associated Workflow Rules, etc if you used force:source:push (or if it were part of a package version).